# How to recovery files from formatted HDD by UBUNTU?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

Before installation Ubuntu 16.04 I used Windows. It were two disks, after I did  formatting HDD and installed Ubuntu.

Can I restore any files now from Ubuntu? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes and no, it depends. The more you use the drive where the files were less are the chances.

Comment: You should shutdown your PC and start it from live CD. Then install on this live CD's system data recovery package (you can give a try to testdisk).

Comment: Can you recommend recovery package?

Answer (score 2):

If you have formatted those disks (used the Ubuntu installer to repartition, format and install onto those disks) then you are loosing your data all the time; every time those disks are written to, your old blocks of data are being overwritten. Given that the filesystem that you installed with Ubuntu (likely EXT3/EXT4) is completely different to the exFAT or NTFS filesystem that Windows would have used, you will be writing *all over* that data. As CelticWarrior has said in your posts comments, the more you use those drives - the less are the chances of recovery.

Formating drives tends to take place when you don't want the data on that drive anymore.

Use something like Ultimate Boot CD (http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html) to boot to a live environment, not touching your hard drive and attempt to recover data. UBCD has file recovery tools which may be able to retrieve the blocks of data that have *not yet* been overwritten. There are two videos [here](http://www.defcon-5.com/noc/video.cfm?docid=392) which may be of use in doing this.